# Keep longest substring if condition matches

Tags: python, string, list

Assume, I have the list of strings as follows:

```
lst = ['practical matter', 'a practical matter', 'As a practical matter',
       'the West', 'the West Coast', 'to Hawaii', 'the West Coast to Hawaii']
```

I want to keep the longest string if the *only* difference between them is a starting "a", "the". For example, I want to keep `'a practical matter'` as there is an `'a'` at the start. Similarly, I want to keep `'the West Coast'` as there is a `'the'` at the start.

```
out = ['a practical matter', 'As a practical matter',
       'the West Coast', 'to Hawaii', 'the West Coast to Hawaii']
```

I tried to do:

```
delete_from_best_constituents = []
for u in best_parse_constituents:
    for v in best_parse_constituents:
        if u.lower().startswith('the') or v.lower().startswith('the'):
            u_part = u.lower().split('the')[-1].strip()
            v_part =  v.lower().split('the')[-1].strip()
            cond1 = all([w.lower() not in STOP for w in u_part.split()])
            cond2 = all([w.lower() not in STOP for w in v_part.split()])
            if u_part == v.lower() or v_part == u.lower() and cond1 and cond2:
                if not u.lower().startswith('the'):
                    delete_from_best_constituents.append(u)
```

But I am looking for a concise and a pythonic approach.

Comment: You'll likely want to use recursion here

Comment: Is the order of the output list important?

Comment: No, the order is not important.

Comment: why is `the West` missing from  the output?

Comment: I want to keep `the West Coast` as it is the longest span. `the West` is the shared string among the two.

Comment: `I want to keep the longest string if the ONLY difference between them is a starting "a", "the"`. The difference between `the West Coast` and `the West` is `Coast`. The only difference is neither `the` nor `a`.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear. If the common string starts-with `(a|the)`, then we also take the longest span into account.

Comment: What criteria is used to determine  that a set of two strings is common? In the case of `the West` and `the West Coast`, only 8/14  characters are common.

Comment: I mean they share the same set of words `"the"`, `"West"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to understand the filter criteria you mentioned, but as you asked for a more pythonic way for your code you might try to write a function that specifies if a string is accepted and use list comprehension with a filter method.

```
def isValid(e,arr):
    for a in arr:

        #might break if the same string is contained twice in `arr`
        #you could convert `arr` to set()
        if e!=a: 

            #modify to match your criteria
            condition = e in a 
            
            if condition:
                return False;
    return True
[u for u in lst if isValid(u,lst)]
```

You can shorten this further by adding a second list comprehension

```
[u for u in lst if not any(
        [ (u != v) and (u in v) for v in lst ]
    ) 
]
```

The above snippets will return the list `['As a practical matter', 'the West Coast to Hawaii']`.